# Sync Azure AD users TO On-Prem AD

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have Azure AD with about 50 users. These users were made when we purchased Office365. Let's say domain on Azure AD is example.com. (username@example.com)
Locally, we use on-prem AD to authenticate computers as well as the wirelss network via RADIUS. Let's say the local domain is corp.example.com. (username@corp.example.com)

Now what I need is to unify the usernames and passwords. I want usernames and passwords that are in Azure AD to be used on prem as well. (So we let go of corp.example.com and move to example.com on both Azure AD and On-Prem AD).

**What is the process to achieve this result?**  I am okay with making any changes to local or Azure AD as long as I get to use username@example.com for both for Azure AD and Local AD authentication.

P.S : my understanding is that locally you can't use a domain name that resolves to a website? (so I can't remake the on-prem AD to use example.com ? )

Answer (score 0):

> Sync Azure AD users TO On-Prem AD

For now, Azure does not support sync Azure AD users to on-prem AD (only support password write back and device write back).

As a workaround, we can **new create** user same as Azure AD, and use **Azure AD connect to sync** this users to Azure AD, that will overwirte Azure AD user, in this way, user will use the same account to login your wirelss network.

For example, we can new create a user `jasontest1@azure.onmicrosoft.com` on your on-prem AD, user account same as your Azure AD. After that completed, we can download Azure AD connect to sync on-prem user `jasontest1@azure.onmicrosoft.com` to your Azure AD. Also the password will overwirte with on-prem password.

After sync completed, we can use new password to login your wirelss network with your Azure AD account.

**Note**:

If we use this workaround, we should create a new user test it, make sure that will not effect your Azure AD account's other application. Because AD sync will overwirte all attributes of your original Azure AD account.